# How to remove an item from .txt file in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a solution to remove the specific item from .txt file in my React project. I used the shipments.txt file for fetching data with Axios to create a DataTable. (shipments.txt is located in public folder) Now, I want to remove item from table when clicked the clear button.

shipmentsTableData.js:

```
  const [shipmentsData, setShipmentsData] = useState([]);

  const getShipments = async () => {
    await axios("http://localhost:3000/shipments.txt").then((res) => setShipmentsData(res.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getShipments().catch((err) => err);
  }, []);

  const onRemoveItem = (id) => {
    const tempShipments = shipmentsData.filter((item, index) => index !== id - 1);
    setShipmentsData(tempShipments);
  };

  const Action = ({ id }) => (
    <MDBox display="flex" alignItems="center">
      <Link to={`/shipments/${id}`}>
        <MDBox mr={1}>
          <MDButton variant="gradient" color="info" iconOnly>
            <Icon>badge</Icon>
          </MDButton>
        </MDBox>
      </Link>
      <MDBox mr={1}>
        <MDButton variant="gradient" color="primary" iconOnly onClick={() => onRemoveItem(id)}>
          <Icon>clear</Icon>
        </MDButton>
      </MDBox>
    </MDBox>
  );
```

As you can see in above, I tried to use filter method for the solution. I know, that's not meet my request as I want to remove item from shipments.txt permanently. Btw my shipments file is designed like json file.

and the rest:

```
    orderNo: (
      <MDTypography component="a" variant="caption" color="text" fontWeight="medium">
        {shipment.orderNo}
      </MDTypography>
    ),
    date: (
      <MDTypography component="a" variant="caption" color="text" fontWeight="medium">
        {shipment.date}
      </MDTypography>
    ),
    customer: (
      <MDTypography component="a" variant="caption" color="text" fontWeight="medium">
        {shipment.customer}
      </MDTypography>
    ),
    trackingNo: (
      <MDTypography component="a" variant="caption" color="text" fontWeight="medium">
        {shipment.trackingNo}
      </MDTypography>
    ),
    status: (
      <MDTypography component="a" variant="caption" color="text" fontWeight="medium">
        {shipment.status}
      </MDTypography>
    ),
    consignee: (
      <MDTypography component="a" variant="caption" color="text" fontWeight="medium">
        {shipment.consignee}
      </MDTypography>
    ),
    action: <Action id={index + 1} />,
  }));

  return {
    columns: [
      { Header: "orderNo", accessor: "orderNo" },
      { Header: "date", accessor: "date" },
      { Header: "customer", accessor: "customer" },
      { Header: "trackingNo", accessor: "trackingNo" },
      { Header: "status", accessor: "status" },
      { Header: "consignee", accessor: "consignee" },
      { Header: "action", accessor: "action", align: "center", sorted: false },
    ],

    rows,
  };
}
```

**So, can you suggest any useful solution in this case?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the data in the file itself, you have to do it on the server. To do so, one of the solutions would be:

1. When user clicks on the button to remove shipping row, send request to the server with id of the shipping data in that row.
2. When server receives the request, it should update file contents by removing data with the received id. For example, read everything as JSON object, filter out item with the id and overwrite file content with the filtered data.
3. After getting the response from the server, update state in the component like you do now by filtering out removed row.

Also, your filter function appears to be wrong. You shouldn't compare id with an index as ids after the removed item will not match. You should compare id from the parameters and id of the item like this: `id !== item.id`.

Comment: In fact, my data doesn't contain 'id' key. I used id as parameter, you can see in there: `action: <Action id={index + 1} />` So, I chose to use index to compare.